# Is an alternative solution possible for replacing cache file in windows 8?

Tags: usb, windows-8.1

I use an USB modem to access internet at my laptop. Operating system is Windows8.1. Last two years it worked well.

The user interference of USB Manager shows "no device" whereas the modem is connected to the system. Ultimately it does not allow me to access internet.

I followed the user guide. It is asking me to delete INFCACHE.1 file from C:\WINDOWS\inf\ directory. It may be a solution for Windows7 earlier. This file is absent in the particular directory. I searched using file searching facility of Windows. This file is absent in the C drive.

Can you give me an alternative solution for Windows8.1?

Edit 1: 
After uninstalling the existing one using control panel, I install it again. For first time it works. I remove the device. Insert it again. It shows same problem "no device".

Comment: Do you see an entry for the modem in Device Manager? Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling the drivers? Does the modem work on another system?

Comment: It works at other's laptop. I checked your suggestion. Please see the edit.

Comment: Uninstall the modem. Reboot. Run [USB Oblivion](http://www.cherubicsoft.com/en/projects/usboblivion) with the real clean option checked. Reboot. Reinstall modem and test.

Comment: After running USB Oblivion system can not detect any USB drive. At least before that I could use my pen drives.

Comment: Did you reboot? All that app does is remove all information about previously plugged-in USB devices from the registry. After that when you plug in any drive Windows will reinstall the drivers. If you used the registry backup option you can restore to your previous state by using that.

Comment: Is reboot same as restart? If it is I have done.

Comment: Open Device Manager, right-click your system name (the top-most item) and scan for hardware changes. Also restore from the .REG backup, then try your drives once more.

Comment: How to restore from the .RGE back up? "scan for hardware changes" does not give any such option.

Comment: Reg backup is created by USB Oblivion if you selected the option (just double-click the file to merge with the registry). If you're still unable to use USB devices then try System Restore. Last option would be to delete all USB controllers from Device Manager and reboot, which should reinitialise the entire USB stack and hopefully fix your problem if it's not a hardware issue.

Comment: How to do system restore? How to do it?